# What is the superclass of "com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutRequest"?

Tags: android, proguard

Im creating an android app and Im working with **proguard**.

The class "com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutRequest"
is throwing an error stating that it cannot find its superclass.

I want to be able to add code to safe-guard its superclass so that it remains in my application after it has fully compiled (and doesn't throw an error).

Step 1 is to identify what the superclass is...
I have looked online for information on the source code for the class (assuming that it will "extend" its superclass.  But I could not find it.

So My questions are: 
1. What is the superclass for "com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutRequest"
2. How did you find that out?

Comment: Can't you just instantiate it in your program and examine it with your favorite debugger?

Comment: Oh, that was a decent idea.  That's new to me.  WHen I run the debugger it shows "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller"  Although when I try to instantiate this class, it shows that there is no ".os." in my libraries.  Not sure what the next step should be...

Comment: When I view the source file, it says that it is not extending any class, so I am not sure why this error is appearing...

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to suggest then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the superclass, you can consider creating a [simple java program using this reflection library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections),

I created a simple cmd line Java and got the below supertypes

```
import static org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getAllSuperTypes(
         com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutRequest.class,null));
   }
}
```

Here is what i see

`[interface java.beans.BeanInfo, class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage, interface java.io.Serializable, class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutRequest]`

Comment: First off - thanks so much so far!  I have previously seen errors regarding these classes and added items to my proguard to "keep" the names of the classes which resolved all but one issue:  The "DatastorePb.PutRequest".  The error I see is still in the question.  I've added more details to the issue in the question above - which includes the errors as seen from android studio.

Comment: Unfortunately no...  My question remains open and the same "The class "com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutRequest" is throwing an error stating that it cannot find its superclass.".  From what I see in the errors, it has not changed.

Comment: @user198923 please clarify in title of your question, and also the description where you say **"So My questions are:"**. Or open another question which focuses on proguard exception.

Comment: Its not really a different question, as the error is stated in the original, but I have posted it. and Ill graciously accept your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227906/android-could-not-find-class-com-google-apphosting-api-datastorepbputrespons

Comment: @user198923 users usually google search and click based on question titles. Thanks for accept i agree it doesn't solve your app bug.