# android - Could not find class 'com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutResponse'

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

Im developing an app that connects to my "endpoints" on google app engine.  I am using proguard to build the app, which does remove some classes from the process.  The place where my app crashes is this one line, initializing my query.  I can put this one line anywhere in my app and see the same weird error.

```
Query query = new Query("NewPostBean");
```

The errors currently seen:

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutResponse; (2181)
Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutResponse;' failed
Could not find class 'com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutResponse', referenced from method com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.makeCall
```

The items in proguard that I thought should fix this issue, but has not.

```
-keepnames class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutResponse
-keep class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutResponse
-keep class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutRequest.** {
    public protects *;
}
-keep class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutResponse
-keep class com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.PutResponse.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keep class com.google.apphosting.api.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keepnames class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage
-keep class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage
-keep interface java.beans.BeanInfo
```

Comment: Which part of your application are you calling Query from? Android or AppEngine?

Comment: Im calling it from android

Comment: Are you trying to access your Datastore directly?  If you're using endpoints, you might want to try sending your query parameters to your backend via endpoints and execute the query on the AppEngine side.

Comment: Ah, that might help.  Once my query executes on the backend, how do I get the data to my application?

Comment: Have you seen an example of how to do that online?

Comment: So you have two options.  If you want to use endpoints with appengine you can try this (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android),  if you want to access the datastore directly, you can use the datastore API (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/)